# Multiuser form in C# isn't saving to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a program to allow users of different types to login in
using the three login options done in C#.

- Usertype
- Username
- Password

The database connection string and the query are working. I have done the login and added data without the `USERTYPE` variable to check connection issues. However, I'm having a problem with this snippet of code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usernamedt, passworddt;

    usernamedt = username.Text;
    passworddt = password.Text;

    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM log_data WHERE username = '" + username.Text.Trim() + "' AND password = '" + password.Text.Trim() + "' ";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlco);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        string usertype = user_type.SelectedItem.ToString(); 

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // state rows in table
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i]["usertype"].ToString() == usertype)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as " + dt.Rows[i][2]);

                    if (user_type.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        customer customer1 = new customer();
                        customer1.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else if (user_type.SelectedIndex == 1)
                    {
                        Staff staff1 = new Staff();
                        staff1.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else if (user_type.SelectedIndex == 2)
                    {
                        Trainer trainer1 = new Trainer();
                        trainer1.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    } // end nested if*/
                } //end check for user type
            }// end for loop
        }// end row count
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The username or password is incorrect,Try Again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    } // end try block
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error ");
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlco.Close();
    }
} // end button LOG IN CLICK
```

Comment: So.... what is your question?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks for reaching out . Whenever I click the Login button to gain access  . The data is not retrieving saved data in the database. However, when I type an incorrect username or password it gives me  the message box "The username or password is incorrect,Try Again"

Comment: When you step through your code, which line isn't working as you would expect?

Comment: Although it's already been stated, it bears repeating and emphasis: **Always use parameterized queries**. Your application, as written, is trivial to hack. Even if it's just as a learning exercise, it's in your best interest to learn how to write code that is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Since I'm using the windows form application. The step into feature doesn't offer much help. The form just loads, waiting on user input.

Comment: But when you put a breakpoint in the above code and step through it, where doesn't it work as expected? e.g. are more than 0 rows returned? Is the usertype correct?

Comment: `sqlco` seems to be defined outside your method, but you close it in your method's finally block?! `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` classes are `IDisposable` so should be properly managed with `using () {}` blocks to avoid resource leaks. Handle both of those inside this method and avoid sharing connections between code.

Comment: Thanks much ill try that